# Open local bundle pdf and share via email or text using swiftui

Tags: xcode, pdf, swiftui

How to Open a local bundle pdf to share via email or text using a swiftui button?

Comment: You need QLPreviewController from QuickLook framework. The possible example how to configure and use it you can see [here](Hide or disable share button from uidocumentinteractioncontroller in swift 5).

Comment: Thank you! What is the example code using SwiftUI button action? I have to use Representable correct? I don’t want to disable the share button at all.  I want to use it!  Any help would be awesome!